# Is there mobile network, and hotspot in elementary OS?

Tags: internet

Is there in elementary OS an option "mobile network" and "hotspot"?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by mobile network? Do you mean support 3G / 4G modems?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have both in Loki. You need to go inside Network Settings and configure it.